# Registered delegate no longer supports restoring

Tags: ios, iphone, core-bluetooth

I am working on Core-Bluetooth,Some times i am getting **Registered delegate no longer supports restoring**, for **[CBCentralManager handleRestoringState:]**,Can any one help me.